# Show data point values in the legend section

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to show the values in the legend section in a chart component of SSRS? I'm using SQLserver 2008.

Something similar to the image below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That would be really fancy, but I don't think it's possible.  You may be able to constrain the width of your bars of the chart and the width of your columns in your table as well as the placement of both to "fake it" though.